# How to Stream a live video along audio with syn via java over Socket?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

Can you suggest to me how to stream a live video (recording from webcam and microphone in syn) over the socket in java? I tried to search but only found ways to stream images over socket not a live video (capturing from webcam) along audio (using mic).

Comment: Can anyone suggest me any tutorial of xuggler API (as it's website was not very useful )or its alternative for streaming live video/audio in java ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really broad question, so it's difficult to provide a satisfactory answer. I can point you to some resources though.

Firstly, a popular protocol for this kind of application is the following:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol

Here is a link to a promising paper going in-depth on how this protocol can be implemented using Java:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228974152_A_Java-based_adaptive_media_streaming_on-demand_platform

Of course, you can also choose to use a pre-existing API (there are plenty of options). Additionally here are some StackOverflow posts that also touch upon this subject:

[Live video streaming using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244861/live-video-streaming-using-java)

[Real-time audio streaming using HTTP - choosing the protocol and Java implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31476798/12089702)

Good luck :)